# How to check current aof/rdb enableness status on a running redis server cli and how to enable them?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

How to check current aof/rdb enableness status on a running redis server's cli ?

How to enable them on cli ?

I'm using redis 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to [ check current aof/rdb enableness status on a running redis server's cli ]

1.1 run `info persistence`

sample output redis 6

```
# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1677893603
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:0
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:561152
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:0
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:753664
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0
aof_current_size:29024
aof_base_size:29024
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:0
```

1.2 run `config get save` for rdb, `config get appendonly` for aof

---

2. to [enable them on cli], run

`config set save 3600 1 300 100 60 10000` for rdb

`config set appendonly yes` for aof